# Getting file size of bmp image

Tags: python, bitmap, byte, filesize

I have a bitmap image and using [this page](http://www.daubnet.com/en/file-format-bmp) I am attempting to read the file size.

In case the link breaks:

> FileSize   |   4 bytes  |  File size in bytes

Here is part of the bitmap `BM\xe6\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006` I want to read from, which as I understand it the file size is between the 3rd and 7th bytes.  So `\xe6\x04\x00\x00`.

I remove all the `\x00` since they are null values and don't tell me anything about the file size, so I used:

```
raw = '\xe6\x04\x00\x00'
character_list = [raw[b:b+1] for b in range(0, len(raw))]
non_empty = [list_ for list_ in character_list if list_ != b'\x00']
```

This returned me: `[b'\xe6', b'\x04']`

Now I get all the values in the list using:

```
size = ''
for byte in non_empty: 
    size += str(ord(byte))
    print(size)
```

Here are the results of the conversion:

`\xe6` > 230

`\x04` > 4

This returns me `2304` (since `'230' + '4'` is `2304`), while my bitmap image has the size of 1,254 bytes and 4,096 bytes on disk.  Clearly this is not the image size.  Where have I gone wrong?

As a side note.  If I take another image of size 90 bytes and run the same process with `Z\x00\x00\x00` it returns 90 as I expected.  (`ord('Z')` returning 90).

Comment: Summing up 230 and 4 isn't the correct operation to calculate the file size. Think of the four bytes `\xe6\x04\x00\x00` as a 4-digit number. The first digit is `\xe6` (or 230), the 2nd digit is `\x04` (or 4) and other two digits are zero. Summing up the digits of a number will obviously not give the number as result. As an example, take the number 23: 2+3 gives 5, not 23. To get 23 from 2 and 3, you have to calculate `2*10+3` (`*10` because it's a base 10 number). Similarly, to get the correct number from 230 and 4, you have to calculate `4*256+230 = 1254` (because it's a base 256 number).

Comment: I would suggest using the built-in [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) module which could handle this and a lot more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From poking around it looks like the byte order for the size in a bitmap is little endian (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian).

There's a built-in method for int that can convert bytes to a integer.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes

So for example:

```
raw = b'\xe6\x04\x00\x00'
size = int.from_bytes(raw, byteorder='little')
print(size)
```

Comment: Much easier and more efficient that I have been trying to use before.  Thank you.